# TFS API - how do I return only projects that an authenticated user has permissions to, instead of the whole list?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm currently returning a list of projects from TFS using the api.

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("some URI"));
var store = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
var projects = store.Projects
```

This works fine.  However, it returns our full list of TFS Team Projects for every user.  Is there a way to return or filter the list such that only the projects a particular user has access to are returned?

This is using TFS 2010.

Answer (score 6):

In TFS 2010, I believe you can do this by [impersonating](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylaf/archive/2009/12/04/introducing-tfs-impersonation.aspx) the user you are interested in when making your calls.

The TFS 2010 API allows (properly authorized) applications to "impersonate" any valid user you want and take action as that user. This is "authorization" impersonation -- you are not authenticating as another user, so there's no password entry, but you are taking action "on behalf of" another user. There's a specific permission you need to have to do this, so your application would need to be *actually* run as a user with the "Make requests on behalf of other users" permission.

Once that's done, the code is pretty simple. You extract the identity you want from your TPC then create a second "impersonated" one under a different context, and use that second context for your actual work:

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("some URI"));
var identityService = tfs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
var identity = identity = identityService.ReadIdentity(
        IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName,
        "someuser", 
        MembershipQuery.None, 
        ReadIdentityOptions.None);

var userTfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfs.Uri, identity.Descriptor);
```

Any action you take on `userTfs` will be done as if the specified username did it; this allows you to query for projects, queue builds, etc. on behalf of other users.

Comment: Using this approach User A (who runs the application and has the make requests on behalf of other users permission) obviously must be a member of the collection to invoke tfs.GetService(). In my case the IIS application pool identity of my custom web application using the TFS api represents this User A. However I do not want to add it to each collection, but just once as TFS server user in the TFS Admin console. Is that possible? I tried using TfsServerConfiguration instead of TfsTeamProjectCollection, but doing so the impersonated identity is different from the one using TfsTeamProjectCollect

Answer (score 1):

If you add `using System.net` then you can use the credential cache and pass the default credentials of the current user to TFS when getting the collection

```
using (var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials))
            {
                var store = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
                var projects = store.Projects                
            }
```